# Jquery Confirm Box retaining to previous request on click of Cancel button

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a Ajax call processed at server side returning an message that I have shown in Jquery Confirm box. Now if user selects Ok on confirm box I have done my separate process, my problem is that on click of cancel I want to retain on Colorbox of Jquery from which Ajax request(and confirm box is appeared) is send

Presently it is happening : that Ajax call is send from a colorbox to server side , returned a message from server side code is shown on confirm box of Jquery , but on click on CANCEL button of confirm box colorbox is also closed which contains processed data. I want to retain on to the colorbox if CANCEL is selected by user on confirm box

Thanks in advance.

```
    jQuery(data.dataset).each(function() {
                        if(this.warnings.length > 0) {
                            if(confirm(this.warnings[0])) {
                                warningConfirmed();
                            }else{
                                return false;
                            }
                        } 
                    });
```

Comment: @jbabey : pasted code snippets for better understanding :)

Comment: " but on click on CANCEL button of confirm box colorbox is also closed" Is it that you are using the same Id for cancel button in both the boxes?

Comment: @SAM Nopes , not at all CANCEL button for confirm is not defined by me, so no case of using its ID :(